# Look up observation date, between two dates in reference data frame, and report another reference value for all observations in R

Tags: r

I have a dates associated with observations for c. 2000 observations, and would like to add a new factor to my observation data 'season'. Each date falls within a season, bound by a start and end date. I have season, start date and end date in a small reference data frame and would like to look up the observation date and deduce which season it belongs to, by which start and end dates it falls between.

I've tried various combinations of within and interval function but cannot get it to report back the season value.

https://rdrr.io/cran/lubridate/man/within-interval.html

Similar questions have been asked on stack exchange but not worded clearly enough for an applicable answer to be given that would help me.

My reference data are as follows:

```
Season <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K")
Start <- c("29-Apr-12","19-Oct-12",
           "29-Apr-13","19-Oct-13",
           "29-Apr-14","19-Oct-14",
           "29-Apr-15","19-Oct-15",
           "29-Apr-16","19-Oct-16",
           "29-Apr-17")
Start <- as.Date (Start,"%d-%b-%y")
End <-  c("18-Oct-12","28-Apr-13",
          "18-Oct-13","28-Apr-14",
          "18-Oct-14","28-Apr-15",
          "18-Oct-15","28-Apr-16",
          "18-Oct-16","28-Apr-17",
          "18-Oct-17")
End <- as.Date (End,"%d-%b-%y")
Reference.df <- data.frame(Season,Start,End)
> Reference.df
  Season      Start        End
       A 2012-04-29 2012-04-29
       B 2012-10-19 2012-10-19
       C 2013-04-29 2013-04-29
       D 2013-10-19 2013-10-19
       E 2014-04-29 2014-04-29
       F 2014-10-19 2014-10-19
       G 2015-04-29 2015-04-29
       H 2015-10-19 2015-10-19
       I 2016-04-29 2016-04-29
       J 2016-10-19 2016-10-19
       K 2017-04-29 2017-04-29
```

And my observation data are as follows:

```
 Date <-  c("25-Apr-14","03-May-14","24-Nov-15","16-Feb-14","02-May-14","21- 
 Apr-17","27-Apr-15","27-Apr-13", "12-Aug-16","16-Apr-14")
 Date <- as.Date (Date,"%d-%b-%y")
 Observation <- seq(1,10)
 Data.df <- data.frame(Observation,Date)
> Data.df
  Observation       Date
            1 2014-04-25
            2 2014-05-03
            3 2015-11-24
            4 2014-02-16
            5 2014-05-02
            6 2017-04-21
            7 2015-04-27
            8 2013-04-27
            9 2016-08-12
           10 2014-04-16
```

My desired output is as follows:

```
> Data.df
      Observation       Date Season
                1 2014-04-25      D
                2 2014-05-03      E
                3 2015-11-24      H
                4 2014-02-16      D
                5 2014-05-02      E
                6 2017-04-21      J
                7 2015-04-27      F
                8 2013-04-27      B
                9 2016-08-12      I
               10 2014-04-16      D
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has been asked before but could not find relevant post at the moment.

Anyway, to answer your question we could use `sapply` and check where each `Date` falls in between the `Start` and `End` date in `Reference.df` and extract the corresponding `Season`.

```
Data.df$Season <- sapply(Data.df$Date, function(x) 
        Reference.df$Season[x >= Reference.df$Start & x <= Reference.df$End])


Data.df
#   Observation       Date Season
#1            1 2014-04-25      D
#2            2 2014-05-03      E
#3            3 2015-11-24      H
#4            4 2014-02-16      D
#5            5 2014-05-02      E
#6            6 2017-04-21      J
#7            7 2015-04-27      F
#8            8 2013-04-27      B
#9            9 2016-08-12      I
#10          10 2014-04-16      D
```

This is assuming that we would have unique `Start` and `End` date for each season and there would be no overlap. If there is an overlap we could use `which.max` to get the first `Season` where it falls in between.

```
sapply(Data.df$Date, function(x) 
  Reference.df$Season[which.max(x >= Reference.df$Start & x <= Reference.df$End)])
```

---

Or a better option using `cut` assuming the `Seasons` are continuous one after another

```
cut(as.numeric(Data.df$Date), 
 breaks = c(-Inf, Reference.df$Start[-1], Inf), labels =  Reference.df$Season)

#[1] D E H D E J F B I D
```

Comment: That's great thanks! Works perfectly, I made one minor tweak to include less/greater than or equal to:    Data.df$Season <- sapply(Data.df$Date, function(x) 
        Reference.df$Season[x >= Reference.df$Start & x <= Reference.df$End])

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `magrittr`, it doesn't save you as much time as an `sapply` but it is a bit easier to follow in case you're sharing this with not-so-expeRienced colleagues:

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

Data.df <- Data.df %>% mutate(Season = case_when(Date > as.Date("2012-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2012-10-18")~"A",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2012-10-19") & Date < as.Date("2013-04-28")~"B",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2013-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2013-10-18")~"C",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2013-10-19") & Date < as.Date("2014-04-28")~"D",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2014-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2014-10-18")~"E",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2014-10-19") & Date < as.Date("2015-04-28")~"F",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2015-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2015-10-18")~"G",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2015-10-19") & Date < as.Date("2016-04-28")~"H",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2016-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2016-10-18")~"I",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2016-10-19") & Date < as.Date("2017-04-28")~"J",
                                                 Date > as.Date("2017-04-29") & Date < as.Date("2017-10-18")~"K"))
Data.df

#Observation     Date        Season
#1             2014-04-25      D
#2             2014-05-03      E
#3             2015-11-24      H
#4             2014-02-16      D
#5             2014-05-02      E
#6             2017-04-21      J
#7             2015-04-27      F
#8             2013-04-27      B
#9             2016-08-12      I
#10            2014-04-16      D
```